# Final consonant doubling in Proper names

Tags: orthography

Webb, Rudd, Barr, Pratt are all proper names that have a double final consonant. What is the reason for this doubling?

Comment: Why do you think there is a "reason"?

Comment: These are proper names that are ***spelled*** with doubled consonant ***letters***. The names themselves have no final double consonant ***sounds***, which don't exist in English. So this is a question about the spelling of proper names in English, which has no spelling rules that apply to proper names. The answer to your question is that at some point somebody spelled those names with double letters and that particular spelling stuck and became canonical. And it happened independently to every single name and family. That's as close as anybody can get.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as John Lawler says there is no logical overarching explanation covering spelling of proper names. Take, for instance, the hair salon _Ooooh Girl_.